# How to automatically logout of chrome on exit?

Tags: google-chrome

I don't want my google account to be logged in to chrome when I launch chrome. Is there a way to do that? I've tried searching for queries like "chrome logout on exit", but so far I haven't found anything that works.

Related: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/oH7VZGY5h9w

Comment: InPrivate should work for your needs. You will not be logged in on launch, and you will be logged out when you close the window. Ctrl + Shift + N, or Command + Shift + N

Comment: But I still want to login and have my settings and bookmarks. I don't see how I can login in incognito mode?